# Opensearch index set ignore malformed doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Opensearch does not want to update ignore_malformed property.

So I have this really simple code to create a new index:

```
PUT testindex001
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "kubernetes": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "annotation": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "kubectl_kubernetes_io/restartedAt": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "ignore_malformed": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to update the ignore_malformed property to true with this

```
PUT testindex001
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "kubernetes": {
                "properties": {
                    "annotation": {
                        "properties": {
                            "kubectl_kubernetes_io/restartedAt": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "ignore_malformed": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me an error

"type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
"reason": "index [testindex001/_VoE6UwcTg6V-3QQ4KigDg] already exists",
"index": "testindex001",
"index_uuid": "_VoE6UwcTg6V-3QQ4KigDg"
"status": 400

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was too fast to ask this as I have resolved it.

```
PUT testindex001/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "kubernetes": {
            "properties": {
                "annotation": {
                    "properties": {
                        "kubectl_kubernetes_io/restartedAt": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "ignore_malformed": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**